# Single Source Shortest Path

Tags: graph, graph-theory, dijkstra, topological-sort

In a DAG, in order to find the shortest distance to all nodes, we can

1. Use Topological sort, then note down all the distances `O(V + E)`
2. Use Dijkstra's `O(ElogV)`

Which time complexity is better?

Comment: what is `N`? ps. dijkstra's algorithm complexity is not O(ElogV)

Comment: I corrected it sorry, it was supposed to be V + E